# Can i remap and compress a NETCDF at the same time?

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, cdo-climate, nco

I got a huge set of data and i need to remap it to a new size of pixel. But this operation generate a big file that fills my hard drive...

i'm using that:

```
cdo remapnn,r7432x13317 petcomp.nc FINAL.nc
```

So, can i compress and make this operation at the same time?

Comment: Did you try the -z option with your command? What did you get?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44111777/7017006

Comment: ps: I corrected the incorrect cdo tag - check the tag meta when selecting ;-) the cdo tag is for "Collaboration Data Objects", a Microsoft technology that is designed to simplify the creation of messaging applications, that is, email!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following modification to your code should work:

```
cdo -z zip -remapnn,r7432x13317 petcomp.nc FINAL.nc
```

Read the CDO user guide to see other compression options if you need to get as small as possible.

Comment: Hey man ! now, how can i "unzip" the file?

Comment: just to add that you can set the zip level from 1 to 9 by specifying -z zip_N - I usually find there are limited additional gains above zip_6, while the file gets slower to read.  answering Bryan, any netcdf decoder handles the compression if it is netCDF4 compliant.